# Make datatip showup in MapPoint

Tags: geolocation

I got MapPoint cause I need to handle multiple selections (users) from 500 -> 20.000 users
I wanna show them off in different charts and print it; that seems to be possible.
I can make heat maps, these circle maps etc.

Here is my issue: I can't get the map to permanently display the actual data in numbers.
When I mark one of the circles (see the image below), I'm shown exactly the amount of users and the location of them in numbers - it popups as a tooltip. I want to keep that on all the circles.

[image]

I can't seem to find a solution in the options.

Does anyone know if it's possible to display these graphics and at the same time get these datatips permanently highlighted?

Answer (score 1):

You can import pushpins (can be an invisible 1x1 custom symbol) and show the names of each Pushpin. When you import the pushpins, set your data as the Name field. 
Also, there is a large MapPoint community at http://www.MapForums.com with lots of experts and also tools and other resources.
hope this helps,
Eric